# How to compare the values with a 2D array elements?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

I'm trying to take the user input from scanner and then use said values to compare it to values in a 2D array

```java
public void valid(int tempRow, int tempCol) {
    if (board[tempRow][tempCol] = "W") {
        display();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Move invalid, try again");
        makeMove();
    }
    setPiece(tempRow, tempCol, "W");
    display();
}
```

This `if(board[tempRow][tempCol] = "W"){` returns the error:

```
incompatable types: java.langString cannot be converted to boolean
```

Here is the array I'm comparing with:

```java
String[][] board = {
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
        {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"}};
```

So for example I'm wanting to take the user input for the row and column, say these are row 1 col 1. Then I want to compare both these to the array and see if `board[1][1] = "W"` if it does then invalid move else place a piece.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
if(board[tempRow][tempCol] = "W")
```

means:

1. Assign the string "W" to `board[tempRow][tempCol]`
2. Test the result to see if it is true.

Which, of course, cannot be done because a string is not a boolean.

You meant to use `==` instead of `=`. But that would also be wrong. Use `.equals()` for string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```java
if (board[tempRow][tempCol] = "W")
```

should be

```java
if (board[tempRow][tempCol] == "W")
```